# Integrating XML authoring tools like Oxygen etc with VSTS for CI

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, oxygenxml

I am exploring the idea of moving/cloning our repos from github to VSTS. Currently code is checked in through to Github. The advantage I would get is that all the teams would be using VSTS and all the bells and whistles offered by VSTS.

1. I have two choices either leave the devs checking in code to github and somehow sync up VSTS and github repos. Or
2. Clone the repository to VSTS itself and have them start checking in to VSTS directly instead of github.
   I am not sure as to which way would be best in long run. And whether there is any plugin availble for Oxygen to be able to check code in VSTS. 
   Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option is definitively the best one for you:

- VSTS Git repositories are just plain standard Git repository you could reach by means of any Git client using authentication over SSH and/or HTTPS to push/pull from it;
- VSTS even allows you to use [SSH key authentication](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate)
- there are [Credential Managers](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/set-up-credential-managers) available for all the major platforms you could use to authenticate easily;
- no useless hassle syncing two repositories, why would you do that? :-)

I certainly suggest you to try the Oxygen Git plugin to connect to a VSTS Git repository and verify that it works as you would expect.

Comment: I didnt know about Credential Manager. I ll certainly try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree and that is exactly what I do with all of my open source projects. I work in VSTS and then publish the code on a successful build to GitHub.

I created a Task for VSTS that syncs your code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.gittasks

And there are also tasks for publishing releases to GitHub.